# LibGDX SerializationException caused by Field not found

Tags: java, json, enums, libgdx

Currently I'm working on the data saving (and loading) part of my game, using LibGDX's JSON output file writing classes. I've been all over Google trying to find a solution, and have gotten close, but no cigar. So far I've succeeded in trying to save an `Array<Object>` to a file, but when I try to read/load the data from the file, I get the following exception:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: cards.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:705)
    at com.towersvault.unbalanced.util.save.SaveHandler.loadCards(SaveHandler.java:91)
    at com.towersvault.unbalanced.util.save.SaveHandler.load(SaveHandler.java:51)
    at com.towersvault.unbalanced.UnbalancedMain.create(UnbalancedMain.java:28)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Field not found: cards (com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array)
Serialization trace:
{}.cards
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:790)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:919)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:703)
    ... 5 more
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"cards": [
    {
        "card": "ID_3",
        "temper": "LAZY"
    },
    {
        "card": "ID_2",
        "temper": "LAZY"
    },
    {
        "card": "ID_1",
        "temper": "LAZY"
    },
    {
        "card": "ID_1",
        "temper": "LAZY"
    }
]
}
```

My source code for the loading method looks like the following:

```
Array<CardData> loadedCards = json.fromJson(Array.class, CardData.class, Gdx.files.local("cards.json");
```

The `CardData` class has two variables, namely `private Card card;` (typing it out, the variable is an enum which I set for the instance of each card), and `private CardTemper temper;` (also an enum which does the same as the other one). There will have to be instances of the cards due to them all not being the same when I implement the rest of the features further on.

I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong, and I think it's mainly due to my lack of experience in dealing with saving and loading game information.

If anyone could perhaps assist me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Clifford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create new class `Cards` like so:

```
public class Cards {
    private Array<CardData> cards;

    public Array<CardData> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    public void setCards(Array<CardData> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }
}
```

and then retrieve values like:

```
Cards cardsJson = json.fromJson(Cards.class, Gdx.files.local("cards.json")); 
Array<CardData> loadedCards = cardsJson.getCards();
```

Another one is to change json file to:

```
[
    {
      "card": "ID_3",
      "temper": "LAZY"
    },
    {
      "card": "ID_2",
      "temper": "LAZY"
    },
    {
      "card": "ID_1",
      "temper": "LAZY"
    },
    {
      "card": "ID_1",
      "temper": "LAZY"
    }
]
```

And then retrieve values like:

```
Array<CardData> fromJson = json.fromJson(Array.class, CardData.class, Gdx.files.local("cards.json"));
```

I would prefer the first variant, but the choice is yours.

Comment: What is the difference between your json formate and the above json formate..I am facing the same issue..Please help me.

Comment: When I am running app through Android studio, I don't see any issue.App runs fine.But When I build apk and install on the device..It Gives me this error..I have tried your first approach but not resolved my issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @patelvatsal The difference is the root object - in the question there is a `cards` and in mine it's a simple plain array. You should post a question, I cannot help much without the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I tried to parse from a JSON string into an object with primitives ... as in Integer instead of int.

Changing the object types to int instead of Integer made it work again.

For clarification this only happened when I changed the project from pure Java to Android 
(apply plugin: "java" to apply plugin: "android" on gradle) for a Java project(using either Libgdx's json or Gson) it worked